# Logging best practices: structure / conditional logging / filtering

Tags: java, logging

I have been working on a project that logs using what are essentially just println statements with a prefixed string tag. I have been looking into implementing support for an actual logging library such as Logback the past few days and had some questions relating to best-practices about logging in general. I know a lot of what I'm doing is probably stupid, but I want to change :)

When I'm extending the code and adding new features, such as testing a new codec, I have been using liberal logging to ensure the code behaves as expected (instead of actual unit tests), and then using constant booleans at the top to disable that logging when the codec is finished (in case it's needed again or a bug is found, I can flip the boolean while testing). I don't know if the granularity that `debug` level provides would be enough and would prefer some way to define levels differently for different features. Leaving these enabled by default would really bloat the console and probably effect performance -- is this what filters are usually used for?

I've also found myself in more than one case prepending spaces to my messages so that I can better follow the flow of the code. I've found this to be really helpful. In a way, the tabbed messages are like a debug-debug level.

```
Doing something
Reading a file
  header of file: ...
  body of file: ...
Back at main
```

What are good practices for logging? Can someone refer me a good resource that I can dig into or explain if what I'm doing is stupid and why it's stupid? What are some alternatives? An open source project as an example would be extremely helpful. Thanks, I appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Some advice:

- Never substitute unit tests for logging only.
- Regarding logging you should log whatever makes you find bugs quicker.
- Log libraries support async logging which will not affect the performance of your application ([log4j2 async logging](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html#:%7E:text=Asynchronous%20logging%20can%20improve%20your,from%20the%20call%20to%20Logger.)). Logback supports async too.
- Do not use booleans inside your code to decide to log or not to log. Use the logging levels (TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR) and set them accordingly. Usually in PROD environment you will use a WARN level and in DEV you can set it on debug.
- Logging on different levels depending on the package is quite useful (you can use appenders to customize this and other stuff).
- In resume, the important is to read the documentation of whatever library you are using

Comment: Another hint: log using slf4j as long as you don't need to access any library-specific feature.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions for how I can log in a hierarchical fashion? I saw this being used for slog in rust as the compact logging output, but I can't seem to find what it's called if it's even common practice. See top half of [here](https://camo.githubusercontent.com/5a3fdd9145084250b8ca8bed2d1952359886be88/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f6d71724738794c2e706e67)

Comment: You can read about the patterns that you can define to the appenders @Collin. If this answer helped you please mark it, thx